# How to get the speed of the sender with veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

in the file TraCIDemo11p.cc, I want to get the speed of the sender, but when i call traci->getSpeed() I obtien the distinataire speed.

can you help me to do this

thank you very much in advance

Comment: Where do you call this function? And why don't you use the speed information from the TraCIMobility module?

Answer (score 2):

Think about how, in a real system, the receiver would know the speed of the sender. Most likely, the speed will have been included as an information element in some wireless transmission. Then, include this behavior as part of your simulation model.